# Azure ARM with Multiple Extensions and multiple VMs

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager

I am bit struggling to understand this Azure ARM template containing multiple "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/extensions" **and** multiple VMs:

[kafka-on-ubuntu/azuredeploy.json](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/blob/master/application-workloads/kafka/kafka-on-ubuntu/azuredeploy.json)

Assuming there will be 4 VMs: 1 for zookeeper and 3 for Kafka cluster repsectively, how can be ensured that the extension (+script) for Zookeper will run on exactly that one Zookeper VM, and how to ensure that the extension (+script ) for Kafka cluster will run on exactly those 3 Kafka VMs?
I am more tempted to believe that each extension run on **all** VMs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behavior seems to be poorly documented, but from the documentation page for the [Windows custom script extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/extensions/custom-script-windows#extension-schema):

> The name of the resource has to be in the format virtualMachineName/extensionName, if this extension is used as a standalone resource in the Azure Resource Manager template.

Which seems to imply that the resolution for where the custom script extension should be executed is based on the name. I imagine this is the case for Linux VMs too.

For the particular example that you are looking at, the name of one of the vms is:

```
"name": "[concat('zookprvm', copyindex())]",
```

whereas that of the extension is:

```
"name": "[concat('zookprvm', copyindex(), '/installzoo')]",
```

so the prefix of the name of the extension must be identical to the VM name.

Comment: thanks Paolo. Well that is interesting and it is actually what I was looking for from documentation point of view. My only observation here is are you sure that the "virtualMachineName/extensionName" corresponds to that of the extension "name" property in the template? And I agree, is poorly documented.

Comment: @toto' Certainly seems to be the case based on the template you provided. Should be easy to verify; what happens if you change the extension name in the template to be something "wrong" like `"[concat('zookprvm', 'foobarbaz', copyindex(), '/installzoo')]",` ?